# Pygame sprites not being drawn

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, sprite

I'm playing with Python, trying to write a (very) simple space invaders game - but my bullet sprites aren't being drawn. I'm using the same graphic for everything at the moment - I'll prettify the graphics just as soon as I have everything else working.  This is my code:

```
# !/usr/bin/python

import pygame

bulletDelay = 40

class Bullet(object):
    def __init__(self, xpos, ypos, filename):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(filename)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = xpos
        self.y = ypos

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))


class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.image = pygame.image.load("spaceship.bmp")       # load the spaceship image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()                     # get the size of the spaceship
        size = screen.get_rect()
        self.x = (size.width * 0.5) - (self.rect.width * 0.5) # draw the spaceship in the horizontal middle
        self.y = size.height - self.rect.height               # draw the spaceship at the bottom

    def current_position(self):
        return self.x

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))            # blit to the player position


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
player = Player(screen)                                       # create the player sprite
missiles = []                                                 # create missile array
running = True
counter = bulletDelay

while running: # the event loop
    counter=counter+1
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             running = False
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    dist = 1                   # distance moved for each key press
    if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:    # right key
        player.x += dist
    elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]:   # left key
        player.x -= dist
    elif key[pygame.K_SPACE]:  # fire key
        if counter > bulletDelay:
            missiles.append(Bullet(player.current_position(),1,"spaceship.bmp"))
            counter=0

    for m in missiles:
        if m.y < (screen.get_rect()).height and m.y > 0:
            m.draw(screen)
            m.y += 1
        else:
            missiles.pop(0)

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))  # fill the screen with white
    player.draw(screen)           # draw the spaceship to the screen
    pygame.display.update()       # update the screen
    clock.tick(40)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions why my bullets aren't getting drawn?

Fingers crossed that you can help, and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bullets are being drawn. But because of the way you wrote your code, you never get to see it! First you draw all the bullets, and then immediately afterwards you fill the screen with white. This happens so fast that you are unable to see them. Try this and you will see what I mean:

```
for m in missiles:
    if m.y < (screen.get_rect()).height and m.y > 0:
        m.draw(screen)
        m.y += 1
    else:
        missiles.pop(0)

# screen.fill((255, 255, 255))  # fill the screen with white
player.draw(screen)           # draw the spaceship to the screen
pygame.display.update()       # update the screen
clock.tick(40)
```

One solution would be to move the screen.fill to before you draw the missiles.

Comment: Aww, damn.  I've been up too long.  That's a really doozy of a brown paper bag error. Thank you so much. I shall go and slap myself and then drink some coffee.